# MS AI: Duplicate event with Persistence Channel

Tags: c#, powerbi, azure-application-insights

We're introducing Application Insights into out Desktop app. Since the user might be off-line when using the app, we're using a PersistenceChannel to make sure the events can be sent in a later session, and we call flush when the app is shutting down ( Dispose() of our Tracker):

```
public ApplicationInsightsTracker()
{
    this.client = new TelemetryClient();
    this.client.InstrumentationKey = InstrumentationKey;

    TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryChannel = new PersistenceChannel();
    TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryChannel.DeveloperMode = true;
}

~ApplicationInsightsTracker()
{
    this.Dispose();
}

public override void Dispose()
{
    this.client.Flush();
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

public override void TrackEvent(ITrackerEvent trackerEvent)
{
    try
    {
        this.client.TrackEvent(trackerEvent.Name, trackerEvent.Properties);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Failed to track event {0}.  Exception message {1}", trackerEvent.Name, e.Message));
    }
}
```

We're also using continuous export to send the event data from Application Insights to an Azure Blob database. We connect Power BI to the Blob database, and the other day the refresh functionality stopped working. We investigated and it turns out we were loading 2 events with the same unique ID. Looking into the blobs we found 2 consecutive blobs with the same event:

```
blob1.blob  - Holds 1 event
{"event":...,"internal":{"data":{"id":"8709bb70-e6b1-11e5-9080-f77f0d66d988"..."data":{..."eventTime":"2016-03-10T11:15:53.9378827Z"}..."user":{..."anonId": "346033da-012d-4cc4-9841-836e5d8f8e32"..."session":{"id":"cb668d2f-9755-4afd-97c2-66cc3504349a"...

blob2.blob - Holds 3 events
{"event":...,"internal":{"data":{"id":"8709bb70-e6b1-11e5-9080-f77f0d66d988"..."data":{..."eventTime":"2016-03-10T11:15:53.9378827Z"}..."user":{..."anonId": "346033da-012d-4cc4-9841-836e5d8f8e32"..."session":{"id":"cb668d2f-9755-4afd-97c2-66cc3504349a"...
{"event":...
{"event":...
```

As you can see the first event on both blobs is the same. We were running tests on the PersistenceChannel having the machine connected / disconnected from the network, and somewhere along the line AI did this.

We're not entirely sure if this is a problem in how we're using it, or a flaw with the library. As you can imagine getting duplicate events through can be quite a pain (specially if you're building a model externally).

Are we doing something odd with AI, or is this a known issue?

Comment: interesting.  is the event right at the end/beginning of the blobs?  the internal.data.id value is assigned when the datapoint is ingested, not when the datapoint is submitted, so even if you *submit* the same event twice, it should end up being 2 distinct events that contain the same information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked with the team that does export, and they said

> the current export pipeline has opportunities for duplicate exports

And it is something they are looking into.

So it doesn't look like you are doing anything wrong, this is just a case you'll need to be aware of, and work around for now.

Comment: Well that doesn't sound great :( Did they mention any open support issue we can use to track the status? We'll try to keep our azure blobs clean by hand, let's hope it doesn't happen too often or there's a fix for it quickly. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

Exported data from AppInsights may contain dupes.

If you are exporting all your data to Power BI, then you can use [Power Query's built-in duplicate removal feature](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Remove-duplicates-Power-Query-d9cffc69-dc5d-4d94-8b66-72779688874d).

Comment: Of course you can... I don't know how I didn't think of that! That should definitely keep the model running. Thanks Assaf